# Attaching a scrollbar to a listbox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I know that there have been some other questions about this, but was hoping to get some help with my current frame configuration as seen below in the code snippet. I have also attached some images, first is with no scrollbar set up. Second is when I uncommented out my scrollbar code.

[image]
[image]

Frame setup:

```
 # -- Top Frame -- #
    self.top = Frame(master, height = 71, bg = self.topColor)
    self.top.pack(fill = X)
    self.bottom = Frame(master, height = 650, bg = self.bottomColor)
    self.bottom.pack(fill = X)
```

Listbox setup:

```
    # myscroll = Scrollbar(self.bottom, orient = VERTICAL)

    Label(self.bottom, text = 'Files Chosen:', bg = self.bottomColor).place(x = 4, y = 110)
    self.qListBox = Listbox(self.bottom, width = 30, selectmode = SINGLE) # I did have yscrollcommand = myscroll
    # myscroll.config(command = self.qListBox.yview)
    # myscroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
    self.qListBox.place(x = 4, y = 130)

    Label(self.bottom, text = 'Deployment Queue:', bg = self.bottomColor).place(x = 360, y = 110)
    self.dListBox = Listbox(self.bottom, width = 30, selectmode = MULTIPLE)
    self.dListBox.place(x = 360, y = 130)
```

Comment: Better put the listbox and scrollbar together inside a frame.

Comment: Ok, can you put another frame inside a parent frame. In this case it would be self.top

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to resolve this. Created three frames that are inside of my master frame as seen below:

```
my_frame = Frame(self.master)
my_secondF = Frame(self.master)
my_thirdF = Frame(self.master)
```

Once I did this I simply put my Lisboxes inside of those frames and placed them accordingly and configured my scrollbars

```
self.qListBox = Listbox(my_frame, yscrollcommand=myscroll_bar, width = 32, selectmode = SINGLE)
```

I still, however, appreciate all the replies :)